# Not able to understand the use of collect() on IntStream

Tags: java, java-8

I was trying following code snippet to understand the `collect` method on `IntStream` to understand. I was trying to result `Hashmap <string, Integer>`.

```
    IntStream.range(0, 4).collect(
            HashMap::new,
            result, t -> result.put("test", somearray.get(t)),
             result -> result.putall()
            );
```

But compilation complains, `can't find symbol variable result`.

As per my understanding I need to pass `(t, value) -> ...` to `accumulatore`, but I am not able to understand compilation issue as well the use of combiner (3rd argument).

Comment: Code should look like this: `IntStream.range(0, 4).collect(HashMap::new, (m, t) -> m.put("test", somearray.get(t)), Map::putAll);`

Comment: @Flown the example in the question is probably wrong... It's the same key `test`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing some brackets there... Besides look at the definitions of `IntStream.collect` it takes two parameters : `ObjIntConsumer` and `BiConsumer`. Both take two arguments as input and return nothing.

```
int somearray[] = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 7 };

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, 4).collect(
            HashMap::new,
            (result, t) -> result.put("test" + t, somearray[t]),
            (left, right) -> left.putAll(right));
```

Answer (score 0):

### compilation error: can't find symbol variable result.

if you don't using brackets when a lambda expression accept more than 1 argument, the first argument `result` will treating as the argument of the method call `collect(?,result,?,?)`.

### Combiner of Stream#collect

The `combiner` parameter accept a `BiConsumer<R,R>` which means your lambda expression will recieving 2 arguments with the same type.

**AND** it is used in *parallel* stream to merge partial results until eventually get the final result. that is something like [merge-sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) of array if you are familiar with it. and @Eugene has been answered in his answer above.

**In short** a `combiner` never be called in *sequential* stream. that you can write a test to check it. here is my test:

```
public class StreamCollectingTest {
    @Test
    public void combinerNeverBeCalledInSequentialStream()  {
        List<Integer> somearray = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);

        Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, 4).collect(
            HashMap::new,
            (result, it) -> result.put("test", somearray.get(it)),
            (result1, result2) -> fail("Combiner was called in sequential stream!")
        );

        // maybe your logic is wrong, the size of map is always less than 2.
        assertThat(map.keySet(), hasSize(1));
    }
}
```